# Docker: able to telnet to remote machines from host but not from container

Tags: docker, networking, amazon-ecs

We have a couple docker containers deployed on ECS. The application inside the container uses remote service, so it needs to access them using their `10.X.X.X` private IPs.

We are using Docker 1.13 with CentOS 7 and docker/alpine as our base image. We are also using `netwokMode: host` for our containers. The problem comes when we can successfully run `telnet 10.X.X.X 9999` from the host machine but if we run the same command from inside the container, it just hangs and it's not able to connect.

In addition, we have `net.ipv4.ip_forward` enabled in the host machines (where the container runs) but disabled in the remote machine.

Not sure what could be the issue, maybe `iptables`?

Answer (score 4):

I have spent the day with the same problem (tried with both network mode 'bridge' and 'host'), and it looks like an issue with using busybox's telnet inside ECS - Alpine's telnet is a symlink to busybox. I don't know enough about busybox/networking to suggest what the root cause is, but I was able to prove the network path was clear by using other tools.

My 'go to' for testing a network path is using netcat as follows. The 'success' or 'failure' message varies from version to version, but a refusal or a timeout (-w#) is pretty obvious. All netcat does here is request a socket - it doesn't actually talk to the listening application, so you need something else to test that.

```
nc -vz -w2 HOST PORT
```

My problem today was troubleshooting an app's mongo connection. nc showed the path was clear, but telnet had the same issue as you reported. I ended up installing the mongo client and checking with that, and I could connect properly.

If you need to actually run commands over telnet from inside your ECS container, perhaps try installing a different telnet tool and avoiding the busybox inbuilt one.