# Telnet from inside container to remote host port not working

Tags: mongodb, networking, containers, port, telnet

I'm trying to telnet from inside a container to a remote host port (27017). I can telnet to the port from outside the container without a problem, the remote host firewall allows the connection, port 27017 is open and mongod is listening, telnet seems to be working fine on the remote host and is installed inside the container, so what would be the issue?

I'm not getting any error message when I try to telnet, the prompt just keeps blinking without any confirmation/error message. There is no network issue as pinging the port works.

Forgive my ignorance if this is a stupid question. I'm just trying to verify that my container would be able to obtain data through a connection to this remote port.

- 1.Tried configuring the firewall
- Restarts everywhere, including services and systemctl
- checked whether port is open and is listening
- pinging for network issues

I tried this:
[Docker: able to telnet to remote machines from host but not from container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036888/docker-able-to-telnet-to-remote-machines-from-host-but-not-from-container)
and the result was: ": open"

Why doesn't telnet work though? Is this a mongo-specific problem?

Comment: If it worked outside the container what result did you get when you did telnet <mongohost> 27017

Comment: The result inside the container was a blinking prompt, as if the telnet session was in progress of connecting, but that the connection couldn't be established. 

Eventually I decided that the connection was established, since I could break out of the blinking prompt with the same escape sequence (^]) as when outside the container. I was trying to see whether the container would be able to reach the mongodb, which turned out to be possible eventually, so I guess the connection was there all along.